# subset files in a folder based on a list

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have a folder "all_images/" with more than 1000 image files named as "Image1.tif", "Image2.tif" and so on..

I have a text file "extract_images_list.txt" which is a list of images that I want to extract from this folder.

Example:

Image23.tif

Image100.tif

Image248.tif

I want to move only those files mentioned in my text file to another folder "extract_images/"

I could only think of

```
  rm (Image1|Image2|Image3|...|...|....|)
```

where I would provide the images that I don't want.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: see this answer in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that this solution can't possibly handle things like the Line Feed character being in a filename:

```
mkdir extract_images 2>/dev/null
while IFS= read -r file; do
  mv "$file" extract_images
done < extract_images_list.txt
```

This goes through extract_images_list.txt line-by-line by reading them into the `file` variable (the `-r` argument is required to make it treat backslashes as literal backslashes, and `IFS=` makes it not strip whitespace), then moves each line to the extract_images directory.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm!! :-)

Comment: Also, GNU 'parallel' can sometimes be an appropriate alternative to a while loop if you're doing zillions of operations and time is actually a factor.